# Whireshark DNS makes additional queries when searching URL

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser, wireshark

An 101 question about whireshark:
I first flushed my DNS and then started capturing my interface with wireshark.
Then I opened google chrome and searched for a webpage.
Finally, wireshark except the first query about the url makes some additional queries for related names/urls. 
for example : 
Searched for www.aueb.gr and dns makes an additional query for art.aub.gr.
Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you search for www.aueb.gr? Did you just type it in the address bar? If so, then maybe chrome tried to look for some additional webpages for whatever reason it had. Try using a console application to query the DNS entries, something like `nslookup` should work.

Comment: thank you for the answer. My point is to analyze why dns makes these additional queries when searching the url from chrome

Comment: Then it is question about chrome and not about DNS. There is a bunch of stuff that web browser will try to look for without being told to do so (another example is favicon.ico). You can try to enable developer tools in chrome and take a closer look at what exactly chrome tries to acquire when opening the web page.

Comment: bialpio thank you for your help.. I have noticed thath www.aueb.gr has a banner about art.aueb.gr. Is it possible that chrome tries to guess your next choices so makes these dns requests?

Comment: If the site has a banner, then the browser will simply try to fetch the banner from the specified address. If it happens that the banner is placed on site with other domain name (in this case, the art.aueb.gr), the browser will try to resolve that name as well in order to issue a request. It will happen for example for images that are present on the site, scripts, cascading style sheets, etc. The browser will basically try to fetch everything it is told to fetch by the page source.

Comment: Thank you ! this is very helpful .. Please change the answer to this so I can accept it.

Comment: Added more details in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using console application for DNS resolution (for example nslookup) during wireshark capture, it should give you exactly what you want. Web browsers or other applications can try to resolve some additional DNS entries, which may be the cause of the issue you are seeing.

For example:

```
nslookup www.aueb.gr
```

As for the behavior of chrome, web browsers will try to fetch additional resources (like images, cascading style sheets, scripts) in order to be able to display the web page correctly. If it happens that the resource is hosted in some other domain (like art.aueb.gr), the web browser will have to first resolve that domain name - and that is why you see  additional DNS queries.